# What does "tempered water" exactly mean in Apple's latest Earth Day commerical called "Can a building breathe"

Tags: phrases

The commercial is about Apple's new naturally ventilated building called "Apple Park". It says "We run chilled water tubing through that concrete mass, and then we use outside air to be our dominant cooling system, and you're using very little energy to get the **tempered water** to do this. So it's a breathing building."

I've searched on the internet for the meaning of "tempered water" and some of them say "tempered water" means "Water in the temperature range from 85°F (29°C) to 110°F (43°C)". So it's like mild hot water. Then why can it help cool the air?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to the headline question is, **tempered water** implies that the water has had it's temperature altered from what the temperature was at source.

FYI @Dan Bron, many technical reference sites support the characterisation of **tempered water** in this way, if you Google you will quickly find e.g.: 
https://www.hawsco.com/engineered-safety-solutions/what-is-tempered-water/

The deeper question, in the second paragraph, as to **why can it help cool the air**, has less to do with matters of language usage etc as addressed on  https://english.stackexchange.com and so,  would more suitably be asked at sister sites like  https://physics.stackexchange.com/ or https://engineering.stackexchange.com/, given that this delves into the areas of physics, engineering, thermodynamics etc.

Comment: Sounds plausible, but can you back it up with a source? Otherwise I could just post the complete "opposite" answer and people would have no way of deciding which of us was correct and which wrong.

Comment: @Dan Bron please post your complete opposite answer. I would like to know about your answer